# SQL command error on "AVG"

Tags: sql

Trying to get average from, but keep receiving error message:

> Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator.

Here's the SQL:

```
select 
        COUNT(Amount)AS "TOTAL Sales Daily",
        MIN(Amount) AS "MIN Sales Daily", 
        MAX(Amount) AS "MAX Sales Daily",
        CAST(AVG(Amount)AS INTEGER) AS "AVG Salses Daily"          
from CMP_SalesDaily_Data;
```

Comment: Why are you storing amount as a string?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! `Amount` should be a numeric datatype - `INT` or `DECIMAL` - whichever - just **NOT** a `Varchar` !!

Answer (score 3):

CAST is in the wrong place.

```
select 
        COUNT(Amount)AS "TOTAL Sales Daily",
        MIN(Amount) AS "MIN Sales Daily", 
        MAX(Amount) AS "MAX Sales Daily",
        AVG(CAST(Amount AS INTEGER)) AS "AVG Salses Daily"          
from CMP_SalesDaily_Data;
```

One way to handle this efficiently, if you have no control over AMOUNT's data type, might be to do it on the way in:

```
select 
        COUNT(Amount)AS "TOTAL Sales Daily",
        MIN(Amount) AS "MIN Sales Daily", 
        MAX(Amount) AS "MAX Sales Daily",
        AVG(Amount) AS "AVG Salses Daily"          
from (
  select cast(amount as integer) as amount from CMP_SalesDaily_Data
);
```

Still, remember to verify that the CAST isn't doing damage to the data in some fashion (such as you don't have things like "N/A" in the data that need to be handled cleanly).

Comment: Also, you have a typo in your column name, probably.  "Avg Salses" sounds sort of like a yummy guacamole, but is probably supposed to be "Avg Sales".

Comment: Deleted mine as this answer came first. This is your problem. However I would also add this. STOP STORING NUMERIC VALUES AS STRINGS and you won't have this problem.

Comment: I'd also further add, `MIN` and `MAX` and even `COUNT` do not do the same thing for `VARCHAR` as they do for `INTEGER`, so it's possible you will get undesirable results from those parts of the query as well (without adding CASTs to them as well).

Comment: Great point @joe I didn't even think of that. All the more reason not to store a numeric value as a string. Use appropriate data types.

Comment: I agree because I didn't create database, prefer int or decimal.

Comment: Added some advice for how to handle this for all fields at once without having a page full of CASTs.  You could do the same thing with a view, as well, if you need to do this in many places in your code.

Comment: I notice you had comments on a few other answers with '264.00' failing to convert.  You can probably just cast it as `decimal` or `numeric` in those cases, for your purposes here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Amount` field might be of type `VARCHAR`. Try `CAST` or `CONVERT` on it before passing it on to `AVG`.

*(Assuming this is SQL-Server)*

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
AVG(cast(Amount AS INTEGER)) AS "AVG Salses Daily"
```

Comment: Received."Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '264.00' to data type int." Hate that the datatype is "varchar"

Comment: try casting it as float then ... AVG(cast(Amount AS float)) AS "AVG Salses Daily"